# Why doesn't my Eventhub-triggered Azure Function fill the "Offset" field when creating checkpoints?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I created a short Azure Function in Python which is connected to an Eventhub.
When run locally, it triggers just fine. When I stop and restart it however, it triggers again for each event stored in the hub, even if it handled that event previously.
In other words, every time I start the function locally, it triggers for every Event still stored in the hub.

I suspected that the issue lies within the checkpoints, so I checked the assigned Blob Storage. The function does indeed create checkpoints, but the "Offset" field is set to "None" instead of the last Event handled. In full, the checkpoint looks as follows (with varying PartitionIds of course):

```json
{"Offset":null,"SequenceNumber":0,"PartitionId":"13","Owner":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","Token":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","Epoch":31}
```

For reference, this is how my function looks:

```py
def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    for event in events:
        logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                     event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(2)
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to save the Offset myself? The way I understood it, not having to care about matters like this is the beauty of Azure Functions.

Comment: You can refer to [Azure Function Event Hub Trigger and Reliability](https://amarplayground.home.blog/2019/01/03/azure-function-event-hub-trigger-and-reliability/) and [Azure EventHubs Checkpoint Store client library for Python using Storage Blobs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob/1.0.0b6/index.html)

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [Azure-Functions](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues) or [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues)

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Turns out I had set the `extensions.eventHubs.batchCheckpointFrequency` attribute in the host.json too high so the function never even wrote a checkpoint.
The checkpoints I found and posted here never belonged to my function in the first place.